# Simplest way to bind C++ methods to an existing JS function's prototype?

Tags: c++, oop, v8

I have several simple C++ classes, for example:

```
class Audio {
public:
    Audio(const char *filename, bool async = true);
    ~Audio();

    Audio *play(int fade = 0);
    Audio *pause();
    Audio *loop(int loops = -1);
    Audio *volume(float volume);
```

I have replicated the structure in JavaScript as follows:

```
var Audio = function(filename, async) {};
Audio.prototype.Play = function(fade) {};
Audio.prototype.Pause = function() {};
Audio.prototype.Loop = function(loops) {};
Audio.prototype.Volume = function(volume) {};
```

And after reading both the documentation and the sources for v8, v8-juice, and a plethora of blogs... I can't find a single reference on how to "override" a JS function with a C++ method.

Ideally, I'd like JS to be in control of class creation/destruction (is this possible?), and have those objects always point to my native functions (PrototypeTemplate?).

I've seriously spent my entire day today reading articles/blogs/code related to this and can't find, what I should hope is, a simple answer.

---

For your sakes, a "simple" answer to me would be something along these lines (wrappers are fine with me; if I have to write wrappers for the creation/destruction that's okay):

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> jsAudioFunction = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(v8::Context::GetCurrent()->Global()->Get(v8::String::New("Audio")));
jsAudioFunction->Setup(/* setup constructor/destructor */);
jsAudioFunction->SetPrototype(/* map native methods to js functions */);
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://developers.google.com/native-client/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't answer the question of binding native code to JS objects, here are the fruits of my labor:

```
static void jsAudioGC(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> object, void *data) {
    v8::Persistent<v8::Object> obj = v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::Cast(object);
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(obj->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) {
        obj->SetPointerInInternalField(0, NULL);
        v8::V8::AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(-sizeof(audio));
        delete audio;
    }
    object.Dispose();
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudio(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::New(args.This()).MakeWeak(NULL, jsAudioGC);

    Audio *audio = new Audio(get(args[0], ""), get(args[1], true));
    v8::V8::AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(sizeof(audio));
    args.This()->SetPointerInInternalField(0, audio);
    return args.This();
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudioPlay(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) audio->play(get(args[0], 0));
    return args.This();
}
```

Inside of my init() function:

```
v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> audio = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsAudio);
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Play", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsAudioPlay));
audio->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
globals->Set("Audio", audio);
```

This does everything exactly the way I want it to; including proper instantiation and garbage collection.

The only regret I have with this approach is that I would like to be able to "only use what is defined." That way these function are only available if the JS "class" has been included (making it possible to have all functions defined and documented in a JS IDE).

Comment: I'm not a fan of accepting my own answers. If someone has a solution to my original question, I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem... but haven't figured out the GC integration stuff yet. For me it was mostly like having two different templates. One FunctionTemplate for the constructor (and instance-generator) and an ObjectTemplate for the generated data with callbacks.

This is an example of a C++ API class:

https://github.com/martensms/lycheeJS-adk/blob/master/v8gl/api/script.cpp

And here's how the JavaScript side looks like:

https://github.com/martensms/lycheeJS-adk/blob/master/v8gl/test/04-script.js

I did it that way because it seems as this is the way the usual data types are implemented. Maybe I move the methods on the prototype later, but I'll see if that makes sense then.